# R TM ngrams showing in most frequent terms but cannot be accessed

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

Working with R{tm}, my problem is that a term shows up in most frequent terms. When i try to inspect an intersect of the dtm with the particular term, i get a blank. MWE here. After regular tm_map transforms, I have a proper `DocumentTermMatrix`. I call terms with frequency more than 10, like so:

```
> findFreqTerms(dtm4, lowfreq=10)
 [1] "bank america"      "cent stake"        "deutsche bank"    
 [4] "fibre network"     "auto industry"     "interest rates"   
 [7] "optical fibre"     "points cent"       "post offices"     
[10] "postal department" "alibaba investment"         
>
```

I want to find out which all documents contain "auto industry"? I run an intersect, like so:

```
> inspect(dtm4[1:10, intersect(dtm4,"auto industry")]).
```

I get zero entries.

```
`<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 10, terms: 0)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 0/0
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 0
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)`
```

The intersect operation works perfectly for unigrams; but this problem sems to be while passing `RWeka::ngrams` to the `dtm`. Is there something wrong that I am doing, or does the 'findFreqTerms()` create a special (virtual?) view, which cannot be accessed by intersect?
Many thanks.

Comment: I am wondering about the 1:10 selection in dtm4, maybe you are not selecting here any document with the word "auto industry"

Comment: @DrVComas: ten documents in corpus. At least one of the ten documents contains "auto industry"; see output of `findFreqTerms(dtm4, lowfreq=10)` and the term appears more than ten times. Yet isolating the term "auto industry" reports nil. I am not sure, but could it be that dtm stores bigrams as unigrams "auto" and "industry" but reports a virtual view of union (auto, industry) when called?

Comment: if you write a reproducible example I could dig a bit in the problem. I can not run something like findFreqTerms(dtm4, lowfreq=10) directly.